# Flutter - Executing build on android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a question when I run flutter run on my project I have the following error, how can I solve this:

**Error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'flutter_full_pdf_viewer'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: /usr/local/share/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s


Exception: The plugin flutter_full_pdf_viewer could not be built due to the issue
above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project and then run.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception states everything clearly

> Failed to find the target with hash string 'android-28'  in:
>   /usr/local/share/android-sdk

Solution

Open the SDK manager and update your Android SDK.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) is CLI for launching and executing intended commands from Offical Android Site